# No matching files ... were found. (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, npm

so I tried to run `npm start` on my react app.
But It's not running, instead it responds like this:

['/Users/macintoshhd/iCloud Drive (Archive)/Documents/Abu Abdillatief/Self Study/vetme/src/.' were found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuNl3.png)

Can anybody help? In previous projects everything runs fine, and I tried to run other previous projects again that has no `.` file in `src` folder, it ran well, no problems. Plus, this one also has no `.` file in `src` folder as well.

I dont know if `.` refers to `index.js` or any other files, but it clearly has no different when it comes to files contained within `src` when initializing `npx create-react app ...` or `create-react-app ...`.

What I've tried:

- Delete `node_modules`
- Re-run `npm install`
- Update `npm` version

I hope this information could help in finding solutions, I cant quite see the problem myself, thank you.

Comment: Go to the project directory & type `pwd` in the terminal. Copy the result and paste it to here.

Comment: here is the pwd: `/Users/macintoshhd/iCloud Drive (Archive)/Documents/Abu Abdillatief/Self Study/vetme`

Comment: Can you check your package.json under "scripts", what do you have as "start"?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, its the same `"start": "react-scripts start"`.. and I tried changing it to `"start": "react-scripts-start"`, still didn't run

Comment: u probably have tried to import something in your codes, there should be a stack trace, is there not?

Comment: What I did was just the usual `npx create-react-app ...` I didn't add anything, I was just checking if it runs correctly, but it didn't...

Comment: Do you use `eslint` ?

Comment: This is a big problem taking place after the latest React update

Comment: @TreverThompson hi, when was the update? Actually I checked on `package.json` of my previous project that was initialised last week, it has different versions  in  `react-scripts` and other things too

Comment: @abuabdillatief Not sure, but I updated react and react-scripts today, on 24-10-2020, and have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I face the problem also, and found this link https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9902

There mentioned that your directory path shouldn't have any space, since the last react update.

```
C:\Desktop\React App (BootCamp)\myApp> npm start
```

After I removed the space from the directory path, it still doesn't works.

```
C:\Desktop\ReactApp(BootCamp)\myApp> npm start
```

Then I tried to remove the parenthesis also... and it works.

```
C:\Desktop\ReactAppFromBootCamp\myApp> npm start
```

Comment: hi,  its weird, my current directory has space in its parent folder's name, and it works well too.. in my case, as long as the directory path doesn't contain the `Archive`, it runs well

Comment: Removing parenthesis  from a parent folder worked for me.
Thanks a lot, struggled a lot to get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue after I deleted everything in the `src` dir and all I had to do to fix the problem was to stop the server with `ctrl+c` and then `npm start`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very weird, I had the same issue with a new project I created and there is no way to make it work.
The solution for me was to copy all the files from a working project (instead of creating a new react app) and then it ran fine.

Comment: Hi, a friend of mine suggested to move the working folder to `Desktop`, where it has no `(Archive)` in the directory path (as you can see in my problem, it goes through that path and it might cause the app not being able to find whatever the `.` is. But what's weird is that if I move other projects to this same path, it works just fine, idk why

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem... it happens to me when I run create-react-app in a particular folder. it doesn't happens when I run it a in a new directory.. still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

anyway..

I tried to move around this new react app folder to any path that doesn't contain `archive` in its directory, it runs well (even though its parent folders has space in its name).

But, my previous projects are located inside a path which contains `archive`, it runs fine too, so I'm not sure if these are due to the latest changes React made or something in that nature.. but at least it runs now and I can continue building my portfolio.

Hope this runs on your machine too :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I created a new app recently using create-react-app tool. Maybe the problem is the path of the folder which includes the react app is too long, or some special characters in the path. When I put my app into a new folder which has a short and simple path, it works. A new problem caused by new updates.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a problem with the new version of React (it has been updated from 16.13.1 to 17. **. **).

I took from my old file "package.json" " `" dependencies ": {" react ":" ^ 16.13.1 "," react-dom ":" ^ 16.13.1 "," react-scripts ":" 3.4. 3 "...}`, removed all files from "src" but did not touch "app.js" and "index.js" and used  `npm i` & `npm start`.

The application started, but I had a problem - there was no "import React from 'react'" in "App.js". check this option.

Answer (score 0):

According to the git hub issue, they mentioned "your directory path shouldn't have any space" but in my case it still do not work, Once I move to app to Desktop and `npm install` and `npm start`, It worked fine but I have no idea what was happening under the hood.